# Javascript regular expression to match French characters

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics, french

I need to match a word with a French character (`dérange`) with a regular expression. So far I have this:

```js
    var text = "An inconvenient (qui dérange) truth";
    var splitText = text.trim().match(/\w+|\s+|[^\s\w]+/g);
    
    console.log(splitText);
```

However, it treats the `é` as a separate letter. Why?

I need a regex within the `match()` method so that the `splitText` object also contains the word `déranger` and not the three words `d`, `é` and `range` as it does now.

Comment: `\w` on MDN:  "Matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]."

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Regular_expression_and_Unicode_characters

Comment: Make your own character class `text.trim().match(/[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ]+|\s+|[^a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ\s]+/gi);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with regex to get all the words in your text, here is a working example:

```js
var text = "An inconvenient (qui dérange) truth";

var splitText = text.trim().split(/\s+/);

console.log(splitText);
```

Comment: Thanks YouneL. Your solution does work but I need to keep every element, even the brackets.

Comment: You are welcome, but if you want to keep elements as they are, it's mush better and fast to use `var splitText = text.trim().split(/\s+/);`  look at this benmark link: [match vs split](https://jsperf.com/performance-of-match-vs-split)

Comment: do you know however how to make the regex recognize the brackets even when if there is space between the two (like in my example: "(qui"). I would like it to become: "(" + "qui". Thank you YouneL

Comment: and I need to keep spaces too (i forgot to add this to the previous message).

Comment: `text.trim().match(/\(|[^\s\)]+|\)|\s+/g);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to part whitespaces from non-whitespaces. However, there are two expressions for non-whitespaces: `\w+` (matching `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+`) and `[^\s\w]+` (matching everything else, except also whitespace - so this is matching the `é` individually. Just combine these two into `[^\s]+` or - simpler - `\S+`:

```js
var text = "An inconvenient (qui dérange) truth";
var splitText = text.trim().match(/\S+|\s+/g);
console.log(splitText);
```

Comment: Work fine. Thanks Bergi.